# Julia - How to efficiently turn to zero the diagonal of a matrix?

Tags: matrix, julia, linear-algebra, diagonal

In Julia, what would be an efficient way of turning the diagonal of a matrix to zero?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `m` is your matrix of size `N x N` this could be done as:

```
setindex!.(Ref(m), 0.0, 1:N, 1:N)
```

Another option:

```
using LinearAlgebra
m[diagind(m)] .= 0.0
```

And some performance tests:

```
julia> using LinearAlgebra, BenchmarkTools

julia> m=rand(20,20);

julia> @btime setindex!.(Ref($m), 0.0, 1:20, 1:20);
  55.533 ns (1 allocation: 240 bytes)

julia> @btime $m[diagind($m)] .= 0.0;
  75.386 ns (2 allocations: 80 bytes)
```

Answer (score 2):

Performance wise, simple loop is faster (and more explicit, but it is taste dependent)

```
julia> @btime foreach(i -> $m[i, i] = 0, 1:20)
  11.881 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime setindex!.(Ref($m), 0.0, 1:20, 1:20);
  50.923 ns (1 allocation: 240 bytes)
```

And it is faster then `diagind` version, but not by much

```
julia> m = rand(1000, 1000);

julia> @btime foreach(i -> $m[i, i] = 0.0, 1:1000)
  1.456 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime foreach(i -> @inbounds($m[i, i] = 0.0), 1:1000)
  1.338 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime $m[diagind($m)] .= 0.0;
  1.495 μs (2 allocations: 80 bytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Przemyslaw Szufel's solutions bench-marked for 1_000 x 1_000 matrix size show that `diagind` performs best:

```
julia> @btime setindex!.(Ref($m), 0.0, 1:1_000, 1:1_000);
  2.222 μs (1 allocation: 7.94 KiB)

julia> @btime $m[diagind($m)] .= 0.0;
  1.280 μs (2 allocations: 80 bytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more general way how to performantly use `setindex!` on an Array by accessing custom indices:
[Using an array for in array indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65041097/using-an-array-for-in-array-indexing/65060271#65060271)

Linear indexing is best performing, that's why `diagind` runs better than the Cartesian Indices.